# Incrementing a value saved in Google Sheets Cache Service

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm trying to store a value using google cache services but it doesn't seem to increment like I want it to. Here's the code -

```
  //Starts a new instance of cache
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  //Puts the value 2 into foo key of Cache
  cache.put('foo', 2);
  //Grabs that value 
  var startMessageRow = cache.get('foo');
  //stuff for an email I'm sending using this cached value
  var messageDataRange = sheet.getRange(startMessageRow, 2)
  var message = messageDataRange.getValues();
  //Here's where I'm trying to increment it, but the value is staying at 2
  cache.put('foo','startMessageRow'+1);
```

That last line of code is where I'm trying to increment the value by one each time this script runs, however the value is just stuck at two no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier way to do this. I just put a counter in a random cell and then I just add one to that value every time my script runs. Way easier than using the cache services!

```
  var cellRange = s1.getRange("W726"); //set this string to be the corresponding cell for daily counter
  var cell = cellRange.getValues(); //grabs the value from that cell
  var startMessageRow = cell; //sets StartMessage Row to be equal to the value of counter
  startMessageRow = parseInt(startMessageRow);//ints it

  cell = parseInt(cell); //ints it
  cell+=1; //increments
  cell = cell+""; // strings it
  cellRange.setValue(cell); // puts the new value in
```